# Create zip file to local machine

Tags: java, jsp

I have a below code in which my zip file is getting created on the server machine, i want the zip file to be created in the local machine, below is my code, please check the below code and let me know if anybody has a solution for it .

```
<%!


public static void addToZipFile(String fileName, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    System.out.println("Writing '" + fileName + "' to zip file");

    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }

    zos.closeEntry();
    fis.close();
}


%>


 <%
 String imgID = request.getParameter("iID").toString();
    String epsFile = request.getParameter("epsNm").toString();
    String ZipFile = imgID + ".zip";
    //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:/" + ZipFile);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ZipFile);
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);


 File temp = new File(imgID);
 String absolutePath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
 System.out.println("filepath" + absolutePath);

 String relativeWebPath = "CoverCapPDF/"+ imgID;
 String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
 System.out.println("absoluteDiskPath" + absoluteDiskPath);

 String relativeWebPathEPS = "eps/"+ epsFile;
 String absoluteDiskPathEPS = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPathEPS);
 System.out.println("absoluteDiskPath" + absoluteDiskPathEPS);



    String file1Name = absoluteDiskPath;
    String file2Name = absoluteDiskPathEPS;
    String file3Name = "file2.txt";


    addToZipFile(file1Name, zos);
    addToZipFile(file2Name, zos);

    zos.close();
    fos.close();


%>
```

please help me :)

Comment: Are you trying to zip one file or a whole directory?

Comment: You want to generate a zip file on the server but save it on the client?

Comment: You can't create a file on the user filesystem ! Your jsp code executes server side not on client side. So you need to create a zip file on the server and let the client to download that file.

Comment: i am trying to zip two files. and zip is getting created on the server...but i want  a zip to be directly created on the local machine..

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are dealing with a web application which uses JSP (since the above syntax suggests the same). The answer then is you cannot.

What you can do is

1. Create the file at the server and ask the client to download [refer here](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/servlet-code-to-download-text-file-from-website-java/)
2. Create an applet and the applet can have the zip code (though not recommended for security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use a JSP for this, but a servlet. JSPs are view components, whose role is to generate HTML markup using the JSP EL, the JSTL and other custom tags, but no scriptlet.

Second: you're writing to a FileOutputStream. that obviously writes your zip entries to a file. You want to write your zip entries to the HTTP response. You should thus use the response output stream to write your zip entries.

To tell the browser that you're sending what should be saved as a zip file, use

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```

(this should be called before sending anything to the response output stream)